# ¿Cómo deserealizar un JSON con Retrofit?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

Estoy tratando de deserealizar un Json con Retrofit que tiene la siguiente estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El inconveniente es que los nodos ("01","02","03") pueden aumentar o disminuir y no se conoce con anterioridad la cantidad exacta y además cambian de valor cuando aumentan o disminuye la cantidad de nodos. Cualquier idea o ayuda será bienvenida. Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola!
Los números "1","2","3". Los utilizas para algo o existe una razón para que manden esos numeros?

Comment: Ese es verdaderamente el problema. La estructura de ese json no es modificable, es decir, mi persona que es quien lo consume no puede modificarlos, los números "1","2","3" .... no los utilizo absolutamente para nada, y por tales números no encuentro la forma de almacenar la respuesta en una estructura de datos. Lo más curioso es que la respuesta del servidor es 200 así le diga al Call que voy a recibir un JSONObject, ResponseBody u otra estructura definida por mi.

Comment: Puedes utilizar la clase Gson con Retrofit para deserializar tu respuesta. Es decir que puedes tener un interceptor que lea ese json y luego puedas realizar un parseo manual. Ahora para la estructura de Json que estas mostrando no ayuda mucho pero si aplicas un `TypeAdapter` puedes interceptar ese Json y obtener objeto por objeto manualmente. Luego de eso tendrías que crear tu arreglo manualmente y guardar objeto por objeto. Adjunto un ejemplo que realizé con TypeAdapter : https://github.com/RaulitoGC/Technology-Store-App/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/rguzman/techstore/data/net/serializer/

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo en responderme. Voy a probar lo que me sugieres sin duda alguna y te mantengo del progreso. Gracias nuevamente

Comment: Hola tengo una duda, ¿como aplico el TypeAdater que me comentas? Esto es lo que tengo en la llamada:                                                                 
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://externalxfaxprounico.com" + mPort)
                    //.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(new ProductTypeAdapterSerializer().create()) ???
                    .client(client)
                    .build();

Comment: Cuando creas tu objeto de retrofit acepta como parámetro un objeto Gson ".addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))" y cuando construyes tu objeto Gson debes incluirle el TypeAdapter "new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapterFactory(new ProductTypeAdapterSerializer()).create();"